# Swift CoreData, saving data via a many to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

To any or all,
I am looking for assistance with some functionality regarding Swift CoreData, specifically when saving data to two entities that have ‘many-to-many' relationship.

I have searched through this site and am also enrolled in three different uDemy courses, but am struggling to make the app I’m using for education work as designed.

I have relationships set up…
ChildEntity - toParent & ParentEntity - toChild…  both of these are “to Many”

My function to save data to CoreData is only saving the child, not the parent, and more specifically, is not linking the parent to the child.

I know the relationship (toParent) is of type NSSet but apparently, this is immutable.  I am getting no errors in the console.

I was under the impression that you could save and link data to different entities using the relationship name, i.e. toParent, but again, struggle to see how each attribute and value pair for the parent are saved via the relationship.

```
@IBAction func saveChild(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

let child = ChildEntity(context: moc)

    if let firstName = txtFirstNameChild.text {
        child.firstName = firstName
    }

    if let lastName = txtLastNameChild.text {
        child.lastName = lastName
    }

    child.toParent?.setValue(txtFirstNameMum.text!, forKey: "firstNameMum")
    child.toParent?.setValue(txtMobileMum.text!, forKey: “mobileMum")
    child.toParent?.setValue(txtFirstNameDad.text!, forKey: "firstNameDad”)
    child.toParent?.setValue(txtMobileDad.text!, forKey: “mobileDad”)

    ad.saveContext()
}
```

As this is my first online question, please let me know if you need more information to explain my sticking point.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the parent or assign an existing object as the parent, it doesn't just exist automatically.

Comment: As in create a var representing the ParentEntiy?Then update that variable with the information I need saved into that Entity.

Comment: Will the information then be linked via the relationship?

Comment: Yeah so create a new Parent, or find an existing one. Then set that parent to the child. Not sure about the exact swift syntax but in obj-c it would be `[child addParentObject:parent];`